# Javascript : Async/Await with a loop inside

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, async-await, es6-promise

In my react-native i have a problem with async/await functions.
I need to get all users from database and finally return it. but things are not happening in correct order.

I'm confused how should i use async/await.

is this the right usage of it? Any help is highly appreciated

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NetInfo,
  AlertIOS,
} from 'react-native';

var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
var Loading = require("./Loading");
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
var LOADING = {};
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "oc.db", location: 'default'});
import CodePush from "react-native-code-push";
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import translations from './translations';
I18n.fallbacks = true;

export default class Grab extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            terms: '',
            isLoading: false,
            isConnected: null,
            coursesFetched: false,
            registerFetched: false,
        };
    }

  componentWillMount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
      this.setState({
        isConnected: isConnected
      });
    });

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'change',
      isConnected => {
        this.setState({
          isConnected: isConnected
        });
        console.log('Grab: internet status is', this.state.isConnected);
        this.sync();
      }
    );

    this.GrabData();

  }

  toggleAllowRestart() {
    this.state.restartAllowed
      ? CodePush.disallowRestart()
      : CodePush.allowRestart();

    this.setState({ restartAllowed: !this.state.restartAllowed });
  }

  sync() {
    console.log("Grab: Running manual code push update");
  CodePush.sync(
    {
      installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
      updateDialog: false
    },
  );
}

async getUsers() {
    const tx = await (
        new Promise(resolve =>
            db.transaction(resolve)
        )
    );

    const users = await (
        new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            tx.executeSql(["SELECT * FROM users"],[], (tx, results) => {
                const userList = results.rows
                        .map((row, index) => ({
                            userId: row.item(index).userId,
                            userName: row.item(index).userName,
                            userMail: row.item(index).userMail,
                            active: row.item(index).active,
                            firstName: row.item(index).firstName,
                            lastName: row.item(index).lastName,
                            accessToken: row.item(index).access_token,
                            host: row.item(index).host,
                        }));

                resolve(userList);
            })
        )
    );
    console.log('users to return:', users);
    return users;
};

  async getBookable(users){
    console.log('Exectuing function getBookable. received data:', users);
    let results = [];
    console.log(users.length, ' Users received');
    for(let n=0; n < users.length; n++){
      try {
        let host = users[n].host;
        let access_token = users[n].access_token;
        let userId = users[n].userId;
        let response = await fetch(host + 'event/my_events', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'language': DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale(),
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
          }
        });
        let responseData = await response.json();
        //// Get container details
        if(responseData.container.length > 0){
          for(let i=0; i < responseData.container.length; i++){
            let cnid = responseData.container[i].nid;
            let ctitle = responseData.container[i].title;
            results.push(
              "INSERT INTO containersC (userId, nid, title) VALUES ('" + userId + "','" + cnid + "', '" + ctitle + "')"
            );
            //// Get courses for each container
            for(let j=0; j < responseData.container[i].course.length; j++){
              let course_id = responseData.container[i].course[j].nid;
              let title = responseData.container[i].course[j].title;
              let cost = responseData.container[i].course[j].cost;
              let status = responseData.container[i].course[j].status;
              let period = responseData.container[i].course[j].period.time_sys;
              //// Get details for each course
              try {
                let resp = await fetch(host + 'event/course_detail/' + course_id, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'language': DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale(),
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                  }
                });
                let respData = await resp.json();

                let desc = respData.data.content[0].value;
                let capacity = respData.data.content[1].value;
                let image = respData.data.image;
                let status = respData.data.book;
                let cancel = respData.data.cancel;
                let cd = responseData.data.dates;

                results.push(
                  "INSERT INTO courses (userId, course_id, container_nid, title, cost, status, period, desc, capacity, image, cancel) VALUES ('" + userId + "','" + course_id + "', '" + cnid + "', '" + title + "', '" + cost + "', '" + status + "', '" + period + "', '" + desc + "', '" + capacity + "', '" + image + "', '" + cancel + "')"
                );

                //// Getting lecture dates for each course
                for(let a=0; a < cd.length; a++){
                  let sdate = cd[a].start_time.split(" ");
                  let edate = cd[a].end_time.split(" ");
                  results.push(
                    "INSERT INTO lectures (userId, course_id, title, start_time, end_time, start_date, end_date, room, teacher) VALUES ('" + userId + "','" + course_id + "', '" + cd[a].title + "', '" + sdate[1] + "', '" + edate[1] + "', '" + sdate[0] + "', '" + edate[0] + "', '" + cd[a].room + "', '" + cd[a].teacher + "')"
                  );
                }
                //// End getting lecture dates for courses
                return true;
              } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
              }
              //// End getting details for courses
            }
            //// End getting courses for containers
          }
        }
        //// End getting container details
        return true;
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }

  redirectUser(){
    Actions.tabbar({type: 'reset'});
  }

  async runQuery(query) {
    await db.transaction(tx => {
      return Promise.all(query.map(async (q) => {
        try {
          let results = await tx.executeSql(q, []);
          console.log('Query', q, 'Executed. results:', results);
        } catch(err) {
          console.log('Something went wrong while executing query', q, 'error is', err);
        }
      }));
    });
    return true;

  }

  async GrabData(){
    try {
      let users = await this.getUsers();
      //let [courses, register, evaluation] = await Promise.all([getBookable(users), getRegister(users), getEvaluation(users)]);
      let courses = await this.getBookable(users);
      //let query = [courses, register, evaluation];
      let query = [courses];
      await this.runQuery(["DELETE FROM containersC", "DELETE FROM courses", "DELETE FROM lectures", "DELETE FROM containersR", "DELETE FROM register", "DELETE FROM lectures", "DELETE FROM evaluations", "DELETE FROM fields"]);
      await this.runQuery(query);
      //this.redirectUser();
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  render() {

return(
    <View style={styles.container}><Loading/></View>
  );
  }

}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
});

Grab = CodePush(Grab);
```

Using SQLite for React-Native : https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: `i have a problem with async/await functions` - what **is** the problem?

Comment: @JaromandaX i can't get it working. simply it doesn't work. i need to get all users from database, and then return it.

Comment: @JaromandaX Not if it's a method in the middle of a class.

Comment: @JaromandaX when i'm putting function it gives syntax error. async function getUsers()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a "multi step approach" by wrapping the callback-based calls into promises in order to use the advantages of a synchronous call sequence in the main part of the `async` function and instead of using the loop I would go with `map`ping the rows to the desired data structure.

```
async getUsers() {
    const tx = await (
        new Promise(resolve =>
            db.transaction(resolve)
        )
    );

    const users = await (
        new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            tx.executeSql(["SELECT * FROM users"], [], (tx, results) => {
                const item = results.rows.item;
                const count = item.length;

                const userList = Array.apply(null, Array(count))
                    .map((dummy, index) => {
                        const user = item(index);

                        return {
                            userId: user.userId,
                            userName: user.userName,
                            userMail: user.userMail,
                            active: user.active,
                            firstName: user.firstName,
                            lastName: user.lastName,
                            accessToken: user.access_token,
                            host: user.host,
                        };
                    });

                resolve(userList);
            })
        )
    );

    return users;
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have simply copy & paste it, but it gives syntax error in the line you have used .reduce  , what could it be?

Comment: Autsch. Was a missing `)` before the `reduce`

Comment: may i ask you to update the answer? i tried adding it, still same issue.

Comment: I updated the answer and also get rid of the object data structure. Instead the `userList` is now an array with user objects.

Comment: Thanks. should i use async function getUsers or async getUsers? when i use function it gives syntax error

Comment: It is `async function` according to the spec, but it depends on the location of your function. Is it a method within a class? If so, it has to be `async getUsers() {...}`.

Comment: i've updated my question with whole code. i copy & pasted your function, but it doesn't execute.

Comment: so you change the question, accept the answer, and say it doesn't work!? Odd seeing as your original code looked more like the example code in the react-native-sqlite-storage github page

Comment: @Ataomega You have to move all the async functions into the class as methods.

Comment: @notion I'm so confused, would it be possible for you to give an example?

Comment: @Ataomega Wohaa :) You've moved the functions already. What is the current message?

Comment: @notion , the getUsers function is not returning anything. to test, i put a console.log at first (getUsers) and one at end. it's not reaching the end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125408/discussion-between-notion-and-ataomega).